# Mongoose findOne() callback returning null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find a user in my node app with mongoose by using

```
var User = require('../app/models/user');

function mongoTest() {
    var publicAddress = "0x8a6be8979340faa30020b0c1f617d8fd4309679f";
    User.findOne({"publicAddress": publicAddress}, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        } else {
            console.log(user);
        }
    });
}
```

and `err` and `user` always return `null`. From other questions here ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777907/mongoose-js-findone-always-returns-null) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828053/mongoose-findone-callback-gives-me-null)), this usually seems to be related to mongoose pluralising collections. However, I don't think that's my issue because my users.js has

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
// Have also tried module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'User');
```

For completeness, users.js is

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

// Define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
        username: String,
        password: String,
        pictureCaption: String,
        publicAddress: String,
        contractAddress: String
    }
});
```

Finally, I'm sure that public address exists because I can see it in the mongoDB with Robo 3T.

Comment: Your Mongo collection must be named `users`, is that the case?

Comment: Yes it is the case.

Comment: Aaaah, `publicAddress` is nested inside `local`. You should call `User.findOne({"local.publicAddress": publicAddress}`. `Err` is null because there is no error, and `user` is null because Mongo didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `userSchema` the `publicAddress` is part of `local` object.

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
        username: String,
        password: String,
        pictureCaption: String,
        publicAddress: String,
        contractAddress: String
    }
});
```

You are trying to find an object with `publicAddress` but it's actually inside the `local` object. So you should edit the query as follows to get the result.

```
User.findOne({"local.publicAddress": publicAddress}, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        } else {
            console.log(user);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That was it, apologies for the distraction!

Comment: Shit, I should have posted that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Didn't copy pasted it after seeing your comment. I was going to write it, just got a little late.